# iTunes COM interface - Cannot add song to library

Tags: c++, com, interface, itunes

I'm trying to add a simple .mp3 file to the iTunes library but my program keeps crashing when I call AddFile(). However, when I call get_Tracks() it returns a valid pointer, so I suppose the pointer to IITLibraryPlaylist is valid. What am I doing wrong?

```
IiTunes* p_iTunes;
IITLibraryPlaylist* p_Library;
IITOperationStatus* status;
IITTrackCollection* iTrackCollection;

CoInitialize(0);
if (FAILED(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_iTunesApp, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_IiTunes, (PVOID *)&p_iTunes))){
    p_iTunes->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
}
else{
    p_iTunes->get_LibraryPlaylist(&p_Library);

    p_Library->get_Tracks(&iTrackCollection); // This works, so I suppose p_Library is valid..
    long trackCount = 0;
    iTrackCollection->get_Count(&trackCount);

    p_Library->AddFile(L"C:\\asd\asd.mp3",&status); // crashes here
}
```

Comment: Btw you have error handling done wrong. If `CoCreateInstance()` fails `p_iTunes` will be null and so calling `Release()` will crash your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you pass `WCHAR*` instead of properly allocated `BSTR` and [that leads to undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261515/can-you-cast-a-lptstr-to-a-bstr/5261602#5261602).

You should first allocate a `BSTR` using [`SysAllocString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221458.aspx) (don't forget to release the string later) or better yet use a wrapper class like [`ATL::CComBSTR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh7x9w3f.aspx) or [`_bstr_t`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for managing `BSTR` lifetime.

Comment: @iakovos: You're welcome, just don't forget to free that string later, otherwise you leak memory.